# Cloning back a mirrored local Git repository

Tags: git, clone, mirror

I've mirrored (`clone --mirror`) a local repository with no remote refs, for a backup purpose only.  I notice that the back'd up repo have a 'packed-refs' file with *local* refs inside.

As I try to clone it back I get the same 'packed-refs' file with remote refs such as *remotes/origin/heads/...* instead of local ones. Then, I've to checkout every refs in order to get the local refs.

Is there a way, maybe some `clone` options, able to restore the local refs directly?

Comment: There's nothing special about the packed-refs file vs unpacked refs: `git pack-refs` turns unpacked refs into packed ones, so this is all perfectly normal. Unpacked instances of some particular ref override the packed entry. All that `--mirror` does is (a) make a bare clone and (b) set the default fetch refspec to `+refs/*:refs/*`.

Comment: What I am missing in your question is what you mean by "clone it back". Do you mean: the original repo did get destroyed, and you now want to use the mirror to restore the original?

Comment: Clone it with `--mirror`. `--mirror` instructs Git to copy all remote refs as local refs. Without the mirror option, remote refs will become remote refs.

Comment: @torek Yes, I just mean to restore the destroyed repo from the mirrored one.
@knittl If I use `--mirror` even when I want to restore the destroyed repo, I get a bare repo without a working tree so I cannot use it.

Comment: I think that restoring a bare (i.e. mirrored) repo with the `clone` command always resolves the refs into remote ones even if they were locals. Then you need to checkout the remote refs in order to get them local or modify the 'refs/remotes/origin/branch' to 'refs/heads/branch' into the packed-refs file. Is there an option to prevent the `clone` command to resolve the refs to remotes references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've made a bare clone from some existing clone, and the existing clone has been destroyed (or perhaps you're re-creating it on a new server setup), you have two options:

- create the new bare clone as an empty clone, then use `git push --mirror` *from* the backup/mirror clone *to* the new clone, or
- use `git clone --mirror` from the existing bare clone to make a new bare clone, then optionally remove the remote that this created in the new bare clone.

For example, let's say that the prompt `ec$` here is on the existing mirror clone on `ec.example.com`, and `ns$` is the prompt on the new server, `ns.example.com`:

```
ns$ cd /git && mkdir restored && cd restored && git init --bare
[git messages happen here]

ec$ git push --mirror ssh://ns.example.com/git/restored
```

The `git push --mirror` sets up the new server's clone in `/git/restored`.

Or:

```
ns$ cd /git
ns$ git clone --mirror ssh://ec.example.com/~user/backup/the-mirror restored
[git messages happen here]

ns$ cd restored
ns$ git remote remove origin
```

The `git remote remove` step is optional; it cleans up the traces that show that the restored bare mirror clone came from `ec.example.com/~user/backup/the-mirror`.  Since those traces are only visible to anyone who actually logs on to the server in the first place, this isn't really *required*, but you might like it for whatever reasons of your own.